# symfony drop down with sfguardusers from a specific group

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, sfguard

Using sfguard and doctrine I have the following groups:

Managers
Chefs
Waiters

I have a module for receipts and in the form I want to select a waiter. The default ReceiptForm.class.php populates the fields:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
    'id'               => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
    'sf_guard_user_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('sfGuardUser'), 'add_empty' => true)),
);
```

Its fine as it grabs all the users but how do I configure it to only have users from the group "waiters" or id=3 in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a Doctrine_Query object to the widget with the `query` option as explained in [Chapter 10 - Forms](http://fabien.potencier.org/chapter_10.html) for Propel. It' the same thing using Doctrine.